# How to transpose a table format with awk?

Tags: linux, curl, awk

I have a REST API that gives utilized via cURL the output as below:

```
OK:
groupId: 27
groupPath: My Organization\Management\xyz

groupId: 32
groupPath: My Organization\Management\Database Host\xyz
```

I want the output to be formatted to this:

```
groupId   groupPath
27        My Organazation\Management\xyz
32        My Organization\Management\Database Host\xyz
```

Any leads on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to `ansible`, which is one of tags you have used

Comment: @Daweo Actually, I am running the curl command in ansible task but I didn't add the information in the question and unfortunately I forgot to remove the tag. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a `groupId:` line, save the group ID in a variable. When you read a `groupPath:` line, substitute the saved group ID into the line and print it.

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "groupId   groupPath"} /groupId:/ { g = $2 } /groupPath:/ {$1 = g;print}'
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/kodQ6n)

Comment: Hi @Barmar,
Thanks for the reply. When I run the command, I got the below output.

```My Organazation\Management\xyz
My Organization\Management\Database Host\xyz```

Comment: I just tested it and I got the desired output.

Comment: I am getting the below output.
```
[nagendra@dev Downloads]$ cat text
OK:
groupId: 27
groupPath: My Organization\Management\AAA

groupId: 32
groupPath: My Organization\Management\Database Host\AAA

[nagendra@dev Downloads]$ awk 'BEGIN {print "groupId   groupPath"} /groupId:/ { g = $2 } /groupPath:/ {$1 = g;print}' text
groupId   groupPath
 My Organization\Management\AAA
 My Organization\Management\Database Host\AAA
```

Comment: Actually, for me the groupId is not coming in the output. If I provide the assignment as `$7 = g` then it's working but if I provide as `$3 = g` then I am getting the output as
`27pPath   My Organazation\Management\xyz`

Comment: I used `$1 = g` so that the groupId replaces `groupPath:` in the line.

Comment: I've added a demo link.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The command worked perfectly when I manually created the file but Unfortunately, it is not working as `groupId` is not substituting in place of `groupPath`. I think it is because of the curl output, not sure what exactly is the issue.

Comment: I'll bet the `curl` output has CRLF line breaks instead of LF. Try fixing the file with `dos2unix`.

Comment: Yeah, it has CRLF line breaks and `dos2unix` worked like gem.
Thank you so much!